# Using find_package to include network library from cpp-netlib-0.9.4

Tags: boost, cmake, shared-libraries, cpp-netlib

I am using CMake to generate my make file.

However, in one of my files, I need to use `boost::network::uri::valid(uri_)`. So I have included the header file (`#include boost/network/uri.hpp`) and I am using the `boost::network::uri::valid(uri_)` function.

How can I tell CMake to use this header `uri.hpp` and to add the required library?

I have read that I can use `find_package` but I have no or little knowledge about that.

I am using cpp-netlib-0.9.4.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use

```
find_package(Boost 1.55)
```

to locate the headers and libraries for Boost.  If you have Boost installed in some custom location on your machine, then set `BOOST_INCLUDE_DIR` like this:

```
set(BOOST_INCLUDEDIR D:/Code/boost/boost_1_55_0)
```

The command `cmake --help-package FindBoost` will show you help on the various variables set by `find_package(Boost)` so that you can use the appropriate library variable (if necessary, many Boost libraries are header-only) for your target.  You can see some examples of how to use CMake in conjunction with a downloaded Boost distribution and Boost.Test in my talk on doing [test-driven development with Boost.Test](http://legalizeadulthood.wordpress.com/2014/05/17/c-now-2014-presentations-posted/).